# Clarification on winding number computation

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration

So, the integral
$$
\mathcal{I}_\gamma(z) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \dfrac{1}{w-z}dw
$$
gives the winding number of $\gamma$ around $z$. This should coincide with the number of turns that the curve $\gamma$ describes around $z$ (minding orientation...)

If I take the curve $\gamma(t)= e^{it}$, $t\in[-\pi,\pi]$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}$, then since $z$ is in the interior part of $\gamma$ one should get
$$
\mathcal{I}_\gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 1
$$
but when I try to integrate it I keep getting zero (using principal branch of logarithm: $Log(z) := Log(re^{i\theta}) = ln(r) +i\theta ,\theta\in[-\pi,\pi] )$
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{I}_\gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &=& \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_\gamma \dfrac{1}{w-z}dw \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}-\frac{1}{2}}dt\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2\pi i }Log\left(e^{it} - \frac{1}{2}\right)\displaystyle\vert_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2\pi i }Log\left( (-1) - \frac{1}{2} - \left( (-1) - \frac{1}{2}   \right)\right)\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2\pi i }\left( ln(1-\frac{1}{2}) + i(\pi) - ( ln(1-\frac{1}{2}) +i(-\pi))   \right)\\
&=& 1.
\end{array}
$$

I actually can't believe I got this right. I was getting zero before. I'm changing this question to a solution check.

Comment: Since $e^{-\pi i} = e^{\pi i}$, your calculation is essentially
$$\int_\gamma \frac {dw} {w - z} =
\ln(w - z) \bigg\rvert_{w = -1}^{-1} = 0.$$
This however is correct (for a suitable choice of $\ln$):
$$\int_\gamma \frac {dw} {w - z} =
\ln(w - z) \bigg\rvert_{w = -1 - i0}^{-1 + i0},$$
because $\ln(w - z)$ is an antiderivative on the cut plane, so you have to take the limits at the discontinuity when applying the Newton-Leibnitz formula.

Comment: @Maxim are you telling me it should be zero, not 1?

Comment: Log is not an antiderivative of the integrand, because there is $no$ branch of the logarithm that is even continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. So even though the result is correct, there is a difficulty. The way to get around this is to integrate from $-\pi+\delta$ to $\pi-\delta$ and then let $\delta\to 0.$ Or you can prove a general result about winding numbers, which will give you what you want.

Comment: @Matematleta I know I can use a better path, but I wanted to check for this one. The winding number should be path-independent, right?

Comment: Their are two basic facts worth proving about winding numbers: $1).$  the complement $\Omega$ of $\gamma$  is an open set, and for any $z\in \Omega$, the winding number Ind($z$) of $\gamma$ is constant on the connected component of $\Omega$. that $z$ lies in. $2).\ $ if two curves $\gamma $ and $\gamma'$ are homotopic in a region, then their winding numbers are the same.  $2).\ $ allows you to replace your circle with one centered at $z$ and the calculation is a triviality. To do the integral on your path, you need to back off the neagtive real axis and then yo do get Log as an antiderivative.